# i was using travel wp coupons code problems

Tags: plugins

i was using travel wp-theme in WordPress. i have generated coupons using woocommerce smart coupons plugin the coupon code is applying for the product, but the coupon's discount is not varying according to prices for the same product with two price variations can anyone help me out to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

What is the coupon type you have generated?
The "fixed cart" and "Fixed Product" Coupon will not vary based on product price and "Percentage discount" amount will change based on product price.

Comment: https://www.wpfloor.com/set-up-coupons-woocommerce/ . Please refer the link